# SQL statement to execute cannot be empty or null

Tags: java, oracle12c

```
public boolean commitDatabase(Connection con) throws Exception{
        try{
            con.commit();
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
            String sqlstmt1 = super.getSql("enable_privUserTrigger");
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlstmt1);
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
            String sqlstmt2 = super.getSql("update_Status");
            pstmt = con.prepareStatement(sqlstmt2);
            pstmt.setString(1, "GREEN");
            pstmt.executeUpdate();
        }catch (SQLException e) {
            System.out.println("commitDatabase : "+e.getMessage());
            con.rollback();
            con.setAutoCommit(true);
            throw e;
        }finally{
            if(pstmt!=null) pstmt.close();
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Please tell where the error is!!SQL statement to execute cannot be empty or null..
I am at midst of a dilemma...Help please

Answer (score 1):

```
super.getSql("enable_privUserTrigger");
```

or

```
super.getSql("update_Status");
```

returns `null;` thats the error

> provide more info please

Answer (score 1):

Print to the console actual SQLs that you are trying to execute. One of those probably is empty.

Add System.out.println() like this and see values of sqlstmt1 and sqlstmt2:

```
String sqlstmt1 = super.getSql("enable_privUserTrigger");
System.out.println("sqlstmt1 : "+sqlstmt1);
[...]
String sqlstmt2 = super.getSql("update_Status");
System.out.println("sqlstmt2 : "+sqlstmt2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you initialized your PreparedStatement object properly? I think you need to do something like:

```
PreparedStatement pstmt = con.prepareStament(sqlstmt1)
```